# Como fazer notificação ionic cordova?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic, apache-cordova

Preciso realizar notificações como a do facebook nos celulares, estou fazendo um app usando angularjs, ionic, jquery, javascript e nodejs... existe alguma maneira simples de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Onesignal](https://onesignal.com/), ele é bem simples de utilizar, alem da documentação ser bem completa. Segue um exemplo simples.

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();

    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
      console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    window["plugins"].OneSignal
      .startInit("YOUR_APPID", "YOUR_GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER_IF_ANDROID")
      .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
      .endInit();
  });
}
```

Você pode conferir mais na propria documentação.

Answer (score 1):

Se seu projeto é em ionic 3 você pode usar o Ionic Native....

```
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';

constructor(private oneSignal: OneSignal) { }

...

this.oneSignal.startInit('b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba', '703322744261');

this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
 // do something when notification is received
});

this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
  // do something when a notification is opened
});

this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

Pode também olhar a [documentação](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/).